# Convey 'looping' (in programming)

Tags: traduction, informatique

What is the most natural way to convey the present participle 'looping' as in the turn 'keep looping'? Does 'garder la boucle' sound ok? Or 'tourner en boucle'?

[image]

Comment: "garder la boucle" ne serait jamais utilisé. "Tourner en boucle", oui et pourrait s'utiliser aussi pour une chanson qui se répète.

Comment: You do realize, right, that in the expression "keep looping", the meaning is not guarder. keep on its own is guarder sometimes. But keep+ verb+ing in English means to continue to do something. Maybe you are not familiar with that use of keep.

Comment: Continuez à boucler tant que [etc.] Just using boucler is a translation error.  You have made a mistake in your choice of an answer.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/576966/425462) elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Especially in a comment where terseness is a plus, you can just use *boucler*:

```
# Boucler tant que le nombre saisi par l'utilisateur est différent de zéro
```

[Example #1](https://www.debian-fr.org/t/boucler-tant-que-var-nest-pas-un-chiffre-compris-entre-0-3/32400):

> ***Boucler** tant que $var n’est pas un chiffre compris entre 0-3*

[Example #2](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d674438/autres-langages/general-visual-basic-6-vbscript/vb-6-anterieur/boucle-while-or-ne-marche/#post3947314):

> non tu dis de **boucler** tant qu'il est différent de "#DEBUT"
> OU
> différent de "#FIN"
> donc si tu prends l'expression inverse, tu arrête de **boucler** quand
> LigneLue= "#DEBUT" ET LigneLue = "#FIN" ... donc tu arrête de
> **boucler**

I recommend being suspicious when given examples from textbooks or courses found on the Internet. Many of them have been clumsily translated from English so may contain expressions that would not be used by native speakers, or at least that wouldn't have been their first choice. Better to look at what actual people say in forums.

Here are actual number of pages returned by Google while searching forums of the French site developpez.net:

| Expression | Hits |
| --- | --- |
| ***Boucler*** | 294 |
| ***Faire une boucle*** | 292 |
| ***Utiliser une boucle*** | 261 |
| ***Créer une boucle*** | 167 |
| ***Effectuer une boucle*** | 38 |
| ***Réaliser une boucle*** | 35 |
| ***Exécuter une boucle*** | 11 |
| ***Exécution en boucle*** | 5 |
| ***Continuer à boucler*** | 3 |

As XouDo commented, *garder la boucle* never works in this context but *tourner en boucle* is acceptable. I wouldn't expect the latter to be a source code comment though. It's more used to talk about a piece of music or a video that repeat endlessly.

Finally, never use ***looping*** in French if you want to convey the computer algorithm meaning. The French word ***(un/le) looping*** is well established but is exclusively used to name the kind of loop a plane, a roller coaster or similar moving object sometimes do.

Comment: Oui dans le métier on dit souvent "boucler" tout simplement ou encore parfois "reboucler".

Comment: @Lambie **Keep** looping is not looping. Give me a break.

Comment: @Lambie Tu as mal lu: ***Keep looping while*** → **Boucler tant que**. Un commentaire doit être synthétique, on n'attend pas un roman quand on lit du code. "Continuer l' **exécution en boucle**" n'est pas faux, c'est juste lourdingue. C'est pour ça qu'il est si peu présent dans les forums où j'ai cherché.

Comment: @Lambie La boucle ouvre à cet endroit, elle ne continue rien.

Comment: Oui, c'est la boucle qui continue une fois lancée.

Comment: @Lambie Essaye de lire ce que j'ai écrit avant de dire n'importe quoi. J'ai dit que les informaticiens ne disaient jamais **LOOPING** dans ce contexte, *la loop*, oui, ça se dit mais rarement dans un commentaire.

Comment: @Lambie Quels commentaires sarcastiques sur toi ?

Comment: @Lambie et tu as compris le contraire de ce que j'ai écrit à propos d'Internet.

Comment: Heu, tu parles des discussions sur internet en laissant entendre que j'aurais dit que ce qu'ils disent n'est pas valable alors qu'au contraire, c'est sur la base de discussions que j'appuie mes exemples.  Pour ce qui est des cours, nul doute qu'il y en a de fabuleux. Je conseille seulement d'être prudent. Par exemple celui que tu as choisi dans ta réponse est à chier, c'est du *traduidu*. Merci pour le TO.

Comment: @Lambie Le *keep* est traduit ici par *tant que*. Tu n'a compris ni l'anglais, ni le français, ni le code.

Comment: There is no tant que in English. Keep looping while the user etc. "Continuer à boucler [si on veut] tant que l'utilisateur" etc. Un texte en français est au moins 20% plus long qu'en anglais.  Cours de traduction pour débutants. Ce toi qui n'as pas compris l'anglais. Keep because the program has already **been looping**.

Comment: On ne peut pas continuer à faire quelque chose qu'on a pas commencé, cours de logique pour débutant.

Comment: Ton interprétation de l'anglais n'a aucun sens face au code de la question. On peut manifestement dire *keep + verbe* par anticipation en anglais, mais ça ne passe pas en français.  Je suppose que la forme longue serait *loop and keep looping*.

Comment: Oh come on: Keep looping is speech to the coding. It's a while loop.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, c'est une boucle, et alors ?

Comment: Oui, mais on ne dit quasiment pas *continuer à boucler* en français, ce serait un pléonasme. Le verbe *boucler* suffit à rendre le fait que la boucle se maintient. Une boucle, ce n'est pas qu'un tour en informatique, d'ailleurs on parle de "boucle infinie", on ne dit pas "des boucles infinies".

Comment: @λyoye d'oncques Sorry, My mis-take. ///Keep [verb ing] in French is: Continue à [verb-infinitive]. There is simply no doubt about that. As for Continue à boucler being a pleonasm, that is simply not true. I just do not understand how anybody can object what is so obvious.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but there is the context of the program. It's not clear to me whether the _keep_ is very meaningful in [English](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59380165#59380165) in such a context or just structural, but that's off topic. Consider _continuer à boucler_ might create an ambiguity or some weirdness in this context that _keep looping_ wouldn't introduce. This is no general context here, like _keep applying pressure to the wound_ when someone is already doing so, surely you can see that. The 1:1 won't cut it imho. @Lambie

Comment: @Lambie Tu n'as pas viré le texte de ta première référence. Ce que tu as ajouté confirme que *keep looping* est un raccourci pour *loop and keep looping* ou quelque chose comme ça. L'instruction Python *continue* est décrite comme signifiant *keep looping* or elle n'apparait jamais en début de boucle. Je me répète mais on ne peut pas continuer tant qu'on a pas commencé. Peut être qu'en anglais on peut dire à quelqu'un qui à soif *keep drinking until you are no longer thirsty* mais en français on dira *bois jusqu'à ce que tu n'aie plus soif*, pas *continue à boire jusqu'à...*

Comment: @Lambie Ce texte est du charabia pur traduidu: *Les boucles sont soutenues par tous les modernes langages de programmation* ROTFL

Answer (score -1):

Looping en anglais se dit en français:

**exécution en boucle**, **exécuter une boucle**, et même **boucler**

Par exemple. dans un texte sur le codage:

> LOOPING avec un sous-script Il arrive que la commande LOOP ne
> fournisse pas exactement la fonctionnalité d'**exécution en boucle**
> dont vous pouvez avoir besoin. Dans ce cas, vous pouvez aussi appeler
> un script Analytics distinct pour exécuter une boucle à l'aide de la
> commande DO SCRIPT : DO SCRIPT NomScript WHILE TestConditionnel.
>
> Vous pouvez utiliser l'une de ces méthodes courantes pour choisir
> quand terminer votre boucle : [...]
> [Looping en français](https://www.editions-eni.fr/open/mediabook.aspx?idR=47ee45084ff4d0a9e16401429168c764)

> Comme indiqué dans le premier chapitre, **la boucle fait partie des
> grandes structures de base de l’algorithmique**, et donc de la
> programmation. Passé ce chapitre, tout le reste est une application ou
> une dérivation de ces structures de base. **Les boucles sont des
> structures itératives. Une itération ou structure itérative est une
> séquence d’instructions destinée à être exécutée plusieurs fois**.
> **C’est aussi l’action d’exécuter cette instruction.** Vous entendrez parler parfois de structures répétitives, c’est la même chose dite
> autrement. **Le but d’une boucle est de répéter un bloc d’instructions
> plusieurs fois. Selon le type de boucle, ce bloc va être répété un
> nombre fixe de fois (n fois) ou selon un certain nombre de critères
> (un test de une ou plusieurs conditions) que vous connaissez très bien
> maintenant.**

[mediabook](https://www.editions-eni.fr/open/mediabook.aspx?idR=47ee45084ff4d0a9e16401429168c764)

boucle

> En informatique, une boucle est une structure de programmation qui
> répète une séquence d'instructions jusqu'à ce qu'une condition
> spécifique soit remplie. Les programmeurs utilisent des boucles pour
> parcourir les valeurs, ajouter des sommes de nombres, répéter
> fonctions, et plein d'autres choses.
>
> Les boucles sont soutenues par tous les modernes langages de
> programmation, bien que leurs implémentations et syntaxe peut
> différer. Les deux types de boucles les plus courants sont les boucle
> tout en et le pour la boucle.
>
> Une boucle while est la forme la plus simple d'une boucle de
> programmation. Il indique que tant qu'une condition est valide,
> ****continuez** à boucler** [keep looping]. dans le PHP exemple ci-dessous, la
> boucle while continuera jusqu'à ce que i est égal à num.

[...] [le codage n'est pas cité. Voir le lien ci-après pour le voir.] [itérations](http://Si%20$%20i%20est%201%20et%20$%20num%20est%2021,%20la%20boucle%20affichera%201,%202,%203,%204%E2%80%A6%20etc.%20jusqu%E2%80%99%C3%A0%2020.%20Ensuite,%20la%20boucle%20s%E2%80%99arr%C3%AAtera%20ou%20se%20%22cassera%22%20apr%C3%A8s%2020%20it%C3%A9rations%20parce%20que%20la%20condition%20tant%20que%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20remplie.)

Les verbes itérer et boucler se voient parfois sur les lignes de commande dans les programmes. Mais, ils ne veulent pas dire la même chose.

Une boucle est une structure itérative. D'ailleurs, on parle de "itération de/de la boucle".

Exemple: [Cours Python](https://courspython.com/boucles.html#l-instruction-continue)

> L’instruction continue¶ [c'est à dire: KEEP LOOPING)] L’instruction
> continue permet de passer prématurément au tour de boucle suivant.
> Elle fait continuer sur la prochaine itération de la boucle.

[du lien 2]
for i in range(4):
print("**debut iteration**", i)
print("bonjour")
if i < 2:
continue
print("**fin iteration"**, i)
print("**apres la boucle**")